# android-sql lite- distance between two points using lat long values

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to calculate the distance between two locations. The lat long of one location is hard coded for now ( I will later change it by considering values from gps) the other locations are stored in database. I am using the following query

```
Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT NAME, CONTACT,((LAT -" +
        " LATCUR) * (LAT - LATCUR) + ((LONG - LONGCUR) * 2) * ((LONG - LONGCUR) * 2)) " +
        "AS DISTANCE FROM AMBULANCE ORDER BY DISTANCE", null );
```

where `LATCUR` and `LONGCUR` are the current values. I get the error as there is no column named latcur. What should i do?

I declared the latcur and longcur values as 
public static double LATCUR = 39.991932;
public static double LONGCUR = -83.012352;

code : 
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private final String DBNAME = "SERVICES";
private final String TABLENAME = "AMBULANCE";
public static double LATCUR = 39.991932;
public static double LONGCUR = -83.012352;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

    try {

        sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                TABLENAME +
                " (NAME VARCHAR, CONTACT VARCHAR," +
                " LAT float, LONG float, LATC double, LONGC double);");
```

Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT NAME, CONTACT,((LAT -" +
                    " LATCUR) * (LAT - LATCUR) + ((LONG - LONGCUR) * 2) * ((LONG - LONGCUR) * 2)) " +
                    "AS DISTANCE FROM AMBULANCE ORDER BY DISTANCE", null );

```
        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String NAME = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
                    String CONTACT = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CONTACT"));
                    results.add("" + NAME + ",CONTACT: " + CONTACT);
                }while (c.moveToNext());
            } 
        }

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));


    }
```

Comment: so me the table created code! i wil help u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.....

```
    Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT NAME, CONTACT,((LAT -"+LATCUR+") * (LAT - "+LATCUR+") + ((LONG - "+LONGCUR+") * 2) * ((LONG - "+LONGCUR+") * 2)) " +
 "AS DISTANCE FROM AMBULANCE ORDER BY DISTANCE", null );
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have them quoted.  You need to do all your math outside the quoted SQL string.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that? where should i insert the function to calculate the distance.